# What is the best way to save a hash! block in Rebol?

Tags: rebol, red, rebol2

I am using Rebol2 and would like to persist a [HASH!](http://www.rebol.com/article/0020.html) block.

Currently I am converting it `to-string` then using `save`.

Is there a better way?  For example:

```
r: make hash! ["one" "two"]
```

I want to save this to a file, then load it back to `r`.

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Comment: I edited your question a bit...but you can edit it further.  Perhaps you might provide some sample data you are interested in, and what you expect when you LOAD it back.

Comment: If you use `save` on a hashed block to a file, it saves it as `make hash! ["one" "two"]` .. ok, but I now want to `load` that back into my program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are very near your goal. Just use `save/all` and `load`

```
>> r: make hash! ["one" "two"]
== make hash! ["one" "two"]
>> save/all  %htest r
>> r: load %htest
== make hash! ["one" "two"]
```

If you want the same result in **Red** you just need one command more

```
>> r: do load %htest
== make hash! ["one" "two"]
```

Comment: That's it! .. In Rebol2 at least.. doesn't work in Red

Comment: You did not add the tag **Red**..)

Comment: One thing Ive manged to do with my code is to keep it compatbile with both Rebol2 and Red. This is the first roadblock.

Comment: If you want the same source for **Red** and **Rebol2** use just `save` and `do load`

Answer (score 0):

You do that just like with any other value - `save`, then `load`.

There are zero benefits in using `hash!` for persistent storage, by the way. What `load` gives you back is a plain `block!` (`[make hash! [...]]`). Populating hashtable from this loaded data takes more time compared to just loading `block!`, but gives you faster lookups thereafter.

In other words, you can just:

```
>> save %database [one two]
>> make hash! load %database
== make hash! [one two]
```

As described in the tutorial that you linked.

Comment: I'm working with hash! from the start. I'm trying to avoid having to convert to a block or string, then 'saving' it, only to load the block back and hash! it in the process. 

I don't mind doing that IF it's the better way (faster, smaller db storage) which is the question. save/all seems to avoid this hash! / dehash step.

Comment: @Atomica `save/all` just uses construction syntax to store values and preserves their datatype (+ extra info in specific cases), that's all.

`load` still needs to populate hashtable at runtime when you feed it `#[hash! [...]]`, or you need to `do` it manually in case of `[make hash! [...]]`.

There are no speed / memory benefits from doing what you do - it's textual data either way (well, storing plain `block!` takes less characters, so it saves you a few bytes).

Comment: Well, in that case, save/all is better as it saves the steps.